# Using RxJs with too high of a XHR frequency results in backed up requests

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs, backpressure

I am using `ng-cli` with `Angular 2` and `RxJs`. The simple explanation of what I am trying to do is this: I am using RxJs to continuously make a XHR to a backend REST endpoint. I noticed that if the frequency at which I am making these XHR is 100ms, 500ms, or even 1000ms, by looking at Chrome/FireFox developer tool's network view, I can see that a lot of the XHRs are pending; they start out taking anywhere from 200ms to 1.5s, but as the number of XHRs pile up, these requests then take 10s to 20s to complete; they pile up and all later XHRs end up in pending.

My `TypeScript` code that works with the `RxJs` objects look like the following.

```
private initStreaming(): void {
  this.playSubject = new Subject<boolean>();
  this.pauseSubject = new Subject<boolean>();
  let interval = Observable.interval(100)
    .map(() => this.myService.queryTransactions(this.getQueryRequest()))
    .flatMap(v => v);
  let pause = Observable.from(this.pauseSubject).mapTo(Observable.of(false));
  let resume = Observable.from(this.playSubject).mapTo(interval);
  this.timer = Observable
    .merge(pause, resume)
    .startWith(interval)
    .switchMap<Observable<boolean> | Observable<QueryResponse>, boolean | QueryResponse>(v => v)
    .scan<boolean | QueryResponse, QueryResponse>((acc, curr) => {
      if (curr && typeof curr === 'boolean') {
        return acc;
      } else {
        return curr as QueryResponse;
      }
    }, undefined);

  this.subscription = this.timer.subscribe(
    data => {
      if (undefined !== data && undefined !== data.transactions) {
        if (this.queryResponse === undefined) {
          this.queryResponse = data;
        } else if (this.queryResponse && data) {
          if (this.shouldSwap(this.queryResponse, data)) {
            this.queryResponse = data;
          }
        }
      }
    }
  );
}
```

I've read about `websockets` and that might be a better approach to push the data (if it's changed on the server) to the client, than this approach of pulling the data (regardless of whether it's changed on the server). But that's another post, IMO.

At any rate, any ideas on how to improve this code?

Comment: You need buffer and/or throttle.

Comment: How do I achieve that?

Comment: something like `import 'rxjs/add/operator/debounceTime';` then `observable.debounceTime(1000/* ms */)` should manage the number of requests. The sheer number of operators (there are dozens) that deal with this scenario is hard to grok.

Comment: I think the right observable to debounce is my timer, right?

Comment: yes I believe so

Comment: Debouncing a timer seems a little silly, why not just use a higher interval?